# Reversion Strings and replace a character - RegEx with Php

Tags: php, regex

I have a doubt again on RegEx in Php.

Assume that I have a line like this

```
716/52  ; 250/491.1; 356/398; 382/144
```

I want the output to be

1. Replace all semi-colon with comma. I think I can do this using

   ```
   $myline= str_replace(";", ",", $myline);
   ```
2. Interchange the numbers and replace '/' with a comma. That is, 716/52 will become 52,716. This is where I get stuck.

So, the output should be

```
52,716 , 491.1,250, 398,356, 144,382
```

I know that using sed, I can achieve it as

```
1,$s/^classcode:[\t ]\+\([0-9]\+\)\/\([0-9]\+\)/classcode: \2\,\1/
```

But, how do I do it using preg_match in php?

Comment: Does it need to keep the weird spacing?

Comment: fwiw; sed /a/b/ is the same as preg_replace("/a/", "b", $str)

Comment: What is regular about the inserted string? If the placing of spaces and punctuation is regular and if the values are always integers/ floating numbers at the same places, you might want to do a per-piece preg_replace. The code might be a little weird, but if you can read regex, you can easily spot how values are replaced exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$str = '716/52  ; 250/491.1; 356/398; 382/144';

$str = str_replace(';', ',', $str);

$res = preg_replace_callback('~[\d.]+/[\d.]+~', 'reverse', $str);

function reverse($matches)
{
    $parts = explode('/', $matches[0]);
    return $parts[1] . ',' . $parts[0];
}

var_dump($res);
```

And working sample: http://ideone.com/BeS9j

**UPD**: PHP 5.3 version with anonymous functions

```
$str = '716/52  ; 250/491.1; 356/398; 382/144';

$str = str_replace(';', ',', $str);

$res = preg_replace_callback('~[\d.]+/[\d.]+~', function ($matches) {
    $parts = explode('/', $matches[0]);
    return $parts[1] . ',' . $parts[0];
}, $str);

var_dump($res);
```

Comment: It works alone as a test.php but when merged with my code, I wonder why it says 

`Fatal error: Cannot redeclare reverse() (previously declared in C:\xampp\htdocs\scrap_old.php:85) in C:\xampp\htdocs\scrap_old.php on line 85` 

I am using PHP Version 5.3.5

Comment: @Bhavani Kannan: rename function and callback to something like `my_mega_reverse`. You have some another function with the same name already declared in your `scrap_old.php` file

Comment: Or use an anonymous inline function if you're using PHP 5.3+.

Comment: Thanks deceze, i just figured it out myself too... Good that I am learning better :)

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to Regexen you could try this:

```
echo join(', ', array_map(
     function ($s) { return join(',', array_reverse(explode('/', trim($s)))); },
     explode(';', $string)));
```

Comment: It would probably look good on python but such one-liners on php scare me. +1 anyway

Comment: Why are you using the 'join()' function? I know it's still a valid code, but it's an alias of implode(), and it is probably less confusing on sites like this to use well-documented functions. Not really critique, I was just wondering...

Comment: @zerkms True, PHP syntax is terribly verbose for such things... :(

Comment: @Battle_707: `join` is more regular in other programming languages: python, c#, ruby and just looks more natural ;-)

Comment: @Battle I find `join` more readable (it's shorter and makes more sense, IMO). It's not replaced or deprecated by `implode`, so there's no downside to using it.

Answer (score 3):

```
$str = '716/52  ; 250/491.1; 356/398; 382/144';
$str = preg_replace('(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\/(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)', '$2,$1', $str);
$str = str_replace(';', ',', $str);
```

Uses two capture groups, replacing them in reverse order. See it [here](http://regexr.com?2u1gm).